# Django automaticly save models with Author

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

Django 1.6 Have model and custom User

in settings

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'magazine.Author'
```

models.py

```
# -*-coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
import re
import pytils
import datetime
from sorl.thumbnail import default
import markdown
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField
from django.conf import settings

LANDSCAPE_THUMBS_SIZE = '1200x600'
SQUARE_THUMBS_SIZE = '800x800'
PORTRAIT_THUMBS_SIZE = '800x1200'

"""
some functions heed to content processing
"""
def mark(value):
    extensions = ["nl2br", ]
    return mark_safe(markdown.markdown(force_unicode(value), extensions, safe_mode=True, enable_attributes=False))

def get_image(content, thumbs, crop=None):
    try:
        firstImage = re.findall(r'(?mu)\[(?P<title>.*)\s*\]\((?P<url>.*)\s*\)', content)
        title = firstImage[0][0]
        url = firstImage[0][1]
        if crop:
            thumb = default.backend.get_thumbnail(firstImage[0][1], thumbs, crop=crop)
        else:
            thumb = default.backend.get_thumbnail(firstImage[0][1], thumbs)
        return { 'url' : thumb.url, 'title': title }
    except:
        return None


"""
Users
"""
class AuthorManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=AuthorManager.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class Author(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, db_index=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    objects = AuthorManager()

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

"""
Articles classes
"""

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, help_text="Заголовок")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, help_text="Ссылка")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/category/%s/' % self.slug

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']
        verbose_name_plural = "Категория"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = pytils.translit.slugify(self.title)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(u'Имя', max_length=500, help_text=u'Мелкие')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, help_text="Ссылка")
    content = models.TextField(u'Описание', help_text=u'Колье, серебро, большой текст.. Markdown', blank=True) 
    date = models.DateTimeField('Дата', default=datetime.datetime.now)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name="category")
    tags = models.CharField(u'Тэги', max_length=500, help_text=u'Разделенные ","', blank=True)

    TYPE_OF_POST = (
        ('story', 'История'),
        ('interview', 'Беседа'),
        ('photo', 'Фото'),
    )
    type_post = models.CharField("Тип Записи", max_length=20, default='interview', choices=TYPE_OF_POST)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    # standart
    def get_image_landscape(self):
        return get_image(self.content, LANDSCAPE_THUMBS_SIZE, crop='center')

    # standart
    def get_image_portrait(self):
        return get_image(self.content, PORTRAIT_THUMBS_SIZE, crop='center')

    # index small
    def get_image_square(self):
        return get_image(self.content, SQUARE_THUMBS_SIZE, crop='center')

    # content
    def get_content(self):
        return mark(self.content)

    # main preview
    def get_preview(self):
        content = re.sub(r'!(?mu)\[(?P<title>.*)\s*\]\((?P<url>.*)\s*\)', r'', self.content)
        if len(content.split('\n')) > 2:
            return mark(content.split('\n')[0])
        else:
            return mark(content)

    def get_tags(self):
        tags = re.split(", ", self.tags)
        tags_list = [dict(zip(("name", "url"), (i, pytils.translit.slugify(i)))) for i in tags]
        return tags_list

    def get_description(self):
        if '!more' in self.post:
            post = self.post.replace('!more', '<!--more-->')
            more = u'<div class="post_more"><a href="/%s/">Подробности..</a></div>' % self.slug
            a = post.split("<!--more-->")
            a.insert(1, more)
            return a[0] + a[1]
        else:
            return self.post

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/%s/' % self.slug

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
        verbose_name_plural = "Запись"
        unique_together = ('title', 'content')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = pytils.translit.slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And admin.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from models import Category, Post, Author
from django.contrib import admin


class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (        
        ('Содержание', {
            'fields': ('title',)
        }),
    )

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}

    fieldsets = (        
        ('Дополнительно', {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('slug', 'date')
        }),
        ('Содержание', {
            'fields': ('type_post', 'title', 'content', 'category', 'tags')
        }),
    )
    list_display = ('title', 'date')
    list_per_page = 15


admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)

admin.site.register(Author)
```

But then i try save model, i get an error.

```
magazine_post.author_id may not be NULL
```

i try do like this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

but result with same error.. :(

https://www.monosnap.com/image/4BbZOPjTNmVORVTfSEKujFMmlvCxfF & full trace http://paste.in.ua/9264/

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
```

does not have `author` as a field, and it is a **required** field.

Now, when you are saving the model from the admin, `author` field is `NULL` and according to the database it is not nullable. Hence the error.

Now, to fix it, add `author` as a field in the `Post` admin

Comment: This is bad, author, any author should not be able to change author field.. even see them.

Comment: The admin section should only be accessed by trusted individuals. So it is fine. If this is not what you want just have to override the save method to fill this field behind the scenes

Answer (score 0):

Amazing solve this problem – [django-custom-user](https://github.com/recreatic/django-custom-user)